# No puedo obtener el valor de un diccionario ya que existe

Tags: python, python-3.x, diccionarios

Intenté obtener el valor de un diccionario utilizando una clave pero mientras que hay esta clave me contesta el terminal que no lo encuentra. En efecto aqui esta parte del código:

```
client = oauth.Client(consumer)

response, content = client.request(request_token_url, 'GET')
if response['status'] != '200':
    raise Exception('Invalid response: %s, content: ' % response['status'] + content)

request_token = dict(urllib.parse.parse_qs(content))

print(request_token)

authorize_link = '%s?oauth_token=%s' % (authorize_url,
                                        request_token['oauth_token'])
```

Y aqui esta el error:

```
{b'oauth_token': [b'4atrTgcq2WxunKFE1DCA'], b'oauth_token_secret': [b'22UHzyvEVSMWQBlGqHF53sQ9Fy6rfMHbtPFy9OiiVQ']}
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-18-60b9e2f80da0> in <module>
     35 
     36 authorize_link = '%s?oauth_token=%s' % (authorize_url,
---> 37                                         request_token['oauth_token'])
     38 print("Use a browser to visit this link and accept your application:")
     39 print(authorize_link)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Parece que estás equivocando los tipos. El diccionario que utilizas, en efecto utiliza cadenas, pero de bytes no de texto.

Con el diccionario:

```
>>> request_token = {b'oauth_token': [b'4atrTgcq2WxunKFE1DCA'], 
...                  b'oauth_token_secret': [b'22UHzyvEVSMWQBlGqHF53sQ9Fy6rfMHbtPFy9OiiVQ']}
```

Si comprobamos el tipo utilizado obtendremos:

```
>>> type(b'oauth_token')
<class 'bytes'>
```

y tú estás utilizando:

```
>>> type('oauth_token')
<class 'str'>
```

Así que por tanto, la solución es sencilla:

```
>>> request_token[b'oauth_token']
[b'4atrTgcq2WxunKFE1DCA']
```